# Passing argument to function doesn't get recognized by function

Tags: javascript, html, list

I built a list using javascript and add an eventlistener to each li element like this

```
  for (var i = (page - 1) * records_per_page; i < (page * records_per_page); i++) {
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  li.id= "lijst";
    li.className="lijst";

  var p = document.createElement('p');
  p.className = "name"
  p.id = "Naam"
  p.innerHTML = obj.Name[i];
  li.appendChild(p);
  var p = document.createElement('p');
  p.className = "adres";
  p.id = "Adres"
  p.innerHTML = obj.Adres[i];
  li.appendChild(p);
  var p = document.createElement('p');
  p.className = "gsm";
  p.id = "GSM"
  p.innerHTML = obj.GSM[i];
  li.appendChild(p);
    myUL.appendChild(li);
}

const element = document.querySelectorAll(".lijst");
element.forEach(function(el){
    el.addEventListener('click',function(){
    fillDiv(el);
  })
});
```

When I call my function it doesn't recognize the argument I pass to the function.

```
function fillDiv(el){
    FicheNaam = document.getElementById("FicheNaam");
    FicheGSM = document.getElementById("FicheGSM");
    FicheAdres = document.getElementById("FicheAdres");

    FicheNaam.innerHTML = el.querySelector('.naam').textContent;
    FicheGSM.innerHTML = el.querySelector('.gsm').textContent;
    FicheAdres.innerHTML = el.querySelector('.adres').textContent;
}
```

```js
function fillDiv(el){
    FicheNaam = document.getElementById("FicheNaam");
    FicheGSM = document.getElementById("FicheGSM");
    FicheAdres = document.getElementById("FicheAdres");

  FicheNaam.innerHTML = el.querySelector('.naam').textContent;
    FicheGSM.innerHTML = el.querySelector('.gsm').textContent;
    FicheAdres.innerHTML = el.querySelector('.adres').textContent;
    
}

var current_page = 1;
var records_per_page = 2;
var obj = {
        Name: ["John","Peter","Ben","Jonathan"],
        GSM: ["123","456","789","444"],
        Adres: ["Adress1","Adress2","Adress3","Adress4"],
};

function changePage(page){
  var btn_next = document.getElementById("btn_next");
    var btn_prev = document.getElementById("btn_prev");
    var listing_table = document.getElementById("myUL");
    var page_span = document.getElementById("page");

         
    if (page < 1) page = 1;
    if (page > numPages(obj)) page = numPages(obj);
    listing_table.innerHTML = "";
    
    for (var i = (page - 1) * records_per_page; i < (page * records_per_page); i++) {

      var li = document.createElement('li');
      li.id= "lijst";
      li.className="lijst";
      
      var p = document.createElement('p');
      p.className = "name"
      p.id = "Naam"
      p.innerHTML = obj.Name[i];
      li.appendChild(p);
      var p = document.createElement('p');
      p.className = "adres";
      p.id = "Adres"
      p.innerHTML = obj.Adres[i];
      li.appendChild(p);
      var p = document.createElement('p');
      p.className = "gsm";
      p.id = "GSM"
      p.innerHTML = obj.GSM[i];
      li.appendChild(p);
     myUL.appendChild(li);
    }
    
    const element = document.querySelectorAll(".lijst");
    element.forEach(function(el){
     el.addEventListener('click',function(){
       fillDiv(el);
      })
    });
    
    page_span.innerHTML = page +"/"+numPages(obj);
    
    
}
function prevPage(){
    if (current_page > 1) {
        current_page--;
        changePage(current_page);
    }
}
function nextPage()
{
    if (current_page < numPages(obj)) {
        current_page++;
        changePage(current_page);
    }
}
function numPages(obj)
{
    return Math.ceil(obj.Name.length / records_per_page);
}
window.onload = function() {
    changePage(1);
};
```

```css
#filldiv{
  background-color:grey;
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<div id="filldiv">
<p id="FicheNaam">Name</p>
<p id="FicheGSM">GSM</p>
<p id="FicheAdres">Address</p>
</div>
<a onclick="prevPage()" class="previous" id="btn_prev" aria-label="Previous">
  <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span></a>
<a class="next" onclick="nextPage()" id="btn_next" aria-label="Next">
  <span id="page"></span>
  <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span> </a>
<ul id="myUL">
  
</ul>
```

Included a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/h3o2Lbe8/ and snippet of my code.

I need to fill the div on the right with the information within each li.

Comment: _"it doesn't recognize the argument I pass to the function"_ - That's not what the error message tells you. `el.querySelector()` returns `null` because you're looking for `.naam` but the actual class is `name` -> just a typo

Answer (score 0):

Heres the fix:

```
function fillDiv(el) {
   FicheNaam = document.getElementById("FicheNaam");
   FicheGSM = document.getElementById("FicheGSM");
   FicheAdres = document.getElementById("FicheAdres");

   FicheNaam.innerHTML = el.querySelector('.name').textContent;
   FicheGSM.innerHTML = el.querySelector('.gsm').textContent;
   FicheAdres.innerHTML = el.querySelector('.adres').textContent;
}
```

Explanation:
The code is fine except for a naming issue.
In the function changePage() you used the classname 'name'

And in the fillDiv function you tried to use classname 'naam' in the query selector

```
FicheNaam.innerHTML = el.querySelector('.naam').textContent;
```

An exception occured in the funciton because el.querySelector('.naam') returns undefined and you tried to access .textContent property.

[Exception in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yi9Uh.png)
[Screenshot of your code working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yon09.png)